# Using OpenGL from Go

Tags: opengl, go, mingw-w64, cgo

I am trying to use OpenGL from within a Go program. I *think* I have all of the pieces in place, but I am still not quite able to get it running.

My C compiler is the [64-bit version of mingw.](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/) It is in my `%PATH%` variable, and I have verified it working with the random number example in the `cgo` documentation.

I installed the 64-bit GLEW 1.9.0 by coping the bin, lib, and include folders to the `\mingw\x86_64-w64-mingw32` equivalents in my mingw-w64 installation.

When I try and run `go get github.com/go-gl/gl`, go replies with the following:

```
In file included from attriblocation.go:7:0:
gl.h:5:25: error: enumerator value for '__cgo_enum__5' is not an integer constant
 #define GLEW_GET_FUN(x) (*x)
                         ^
d:\programs\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\gl\glew.h:1956:26: note: in expansion of macro 'GLEW_GET_FUN'
 #define glVertexAttrib3f GLEW_GET_FUN(__glewVertexAttrib3f)
                          ^
gl.h:5:25: error: enumerator value for '__cgo_enum__6' is not an integer constant
 #define GLEW_GET_FUN(x) (*x)
```

These errors continue in a similar fashion for values up to `__cgo_enum__15`. I also get some matching errors coming from the Go side of things for each entry.

Any ideas on what I am missing to get this to work?

**Edit:** Here are the 'matching' logs from the Go side of things.

```
attriblocation.go:42:2: error: initializer element is not constant
 func (indx AttribLocation) Attrib4fv(values *[4]float32) {
  ^
attriblocation.go:42:2: error: (near initialization for '__cgodebug_data[5]')
attriblocation.go:43:2: error: initializer element is not constant
  C.glVertexAttrib4fv(C.GLuint(indx), (*C.GLfloat)(&values[0]))
  ^
attriblocation.go:43:2: error: (near initialization for '__cgodebug_data[6]')
attriblocation.go:44:2: error: initializer element is not constant
 }
```

There is one for every `__cgodebug_data[]` 5-15.

**Edit 2:** I have been asked to attach some logs. [Here is what happens when I compile with GCC 4.8](http://pastebin.com/2EXghL1k), and [Here is what I get with 4.7 and 4.6](http://pastebin.com/MVnbDyz6).

Comment: What do you mean with matching errors? Can you post them as well?

Comment: I added the errors that seem to come from the Go side of the house.

Comment: Try running `go build -a -x` in `$GOROOT/src/pkg/github.com/go-gl/gl` and paste the lines that fail including in addition to the error messages you already posted. These may help.

Comment: I ran it, but did not see any new failures. Here is the full log, in case you are interested. http://pastebin.com/2EXghL1k

Comment: Read [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/mingw-w64-public@lists.sourceforge.net/msg06912.html).

Comment: Huh. Thanks for the information! I will go and look if older versions support Go on Windows.

Comment: I tried the older version of the compiler (kept the same version of GLEW) and had issues still. I have attached new logs in the body of my post.

Comment: For the record, I am seeing the same problems with Go 1.1 on 64-bit Linux. So not a MingW issue.

Comment: It just hit me that I should have mentioned I was on one of the early 1.1 versions of Go - RC1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it is a defect in Go and how the C/Go compilers communicate with each other. The workaround is to set `CGO_CFLAGS=-ftrack-macro-expansion=0 go build`. You could also use `go-1.2rc5` or newer to fix the issue. [This bug has been closed with the previous workarounds/fixes specified](https://github.com/go-gl/gl/issues/108).

Comment: This is actually a defect in go rather than go-gl. There is nothing go-gl can do to fix the problem since it is a problem of compilers talking to each other.